# Trying to ignore when a column does not exist in TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a number of databases that each have a table called User. User is not uniform. Sometimes it has ColumnA, sometimes it has ColumnB, other times it has both. Not the best design, I know, but I didn't build it.

I need to check if

- Column A exists - if so - return the data - if not return a string.
- Column B exists - if so - return the data - if not return a string.
- Check if both exist - if so - return the data

I am trying to use a CASE and when exists but when either of the columns do not exist - I get Invalid column... Is there any way to achieve my goal? Thanks in advance for genuine and kind responses.

```
SELECT
ID,
CASE WHEN EXISTS (select COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'User' and COLUMN_NAME = 'Email Address (90)')
THEN [Email Address (90)]
ELSE 'No email 90'
END AS Email90,
CASE WHEN EXISTS (select COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Instance - User' and COLUMN_NAME = 'E-Mail (85)')
THEN [E-Mail (85)]
ELSE 'No E-Mail (85)'
END AS Email85
FROM "User"
Thanks again.
```

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty slanderous thing to say for someone who's been here a month, posted four whole questions, and had to delete two of them that had nothing to do with moderators (and asked for "kindness" in one of those). Do you have any reference to back that up? Some examples would help, else it's, well, slander. Are you accusing moderators of deleting your previous question and then hacking the database to frame you? You're one special kind of special, huh?

Comment: @Stuckat1337 Do you have anything to back up I have only been here for a month? Try 2010 ;)

Comment: It was hardly relevant to my point at all, since your behavior so far has made it quite obvious you're not sure how things work here. But yeah, "[Member for 24 days](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21235420/chocolatechipnutsack)" is pretty telling. Though I suppose this is probably similar to "mods deleted my post" - something you'd say thinking nobody could, you know, check. Saying moderators lie and twist things and delete and vandalize your post is quite a different thing to say here compared to repeating what your profile says about how long you've been here. One is slander. One isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible but not as you are attempting.

You can use [the trick here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66741/why-cant-i-use-a-case-statement-to-see-if-a-column-exists-and-not-select-from-i/66755#66755) ([DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/c7ezAEoV))

```
SELECT ca.*
FROM   (VALUES('No email 90', 
               'No E-Mail (85)')) DefaultValues([Email Address (90)], [E-Mail (85)])
       CROSS APPLY (
                   --These will be resolved from "User" table if they exist there or DefaultValues otherwise
                   SELECT ID,
                          [Email Address (90)],
                          [E-Mail (85)]
                    FROM   "User") ca
```